# Solving system of three partial differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I have three differential equations:

$$\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial z}=A$$
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial x}=B$$
$$\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}=C$$
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are functions of $(x,y,z)$

How shall I write $F,G,H$ in terms of $A, B, C$?

> EDIT: There is the condition : $\nabla.(\nabla \times \vec{A})=0$
>
> Now how shall I proceed to get a solution?

Comment: I assume the context here is related to the curl of an unknown vector field. There's no unique solution, but you can find a particular solution by setting one of the components $\langle F,G,H \rangle$ to $0$

Comment: You also get an integrability condition from $\text{div}\, \text{rot} V=∇⋅(∇×V)=0$, that is $A_x+B_y+C_z=0$.

Comment: @LutzL I think that's a required condition, otherwise there would be no solution, right?

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, at least no smooth solution, I do not know if there could be solutions in distributions or other ideas of generalized functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to solve

$$ \nabla \times \textbf{V} = \textbf{U} $$

with the condition $$ \nabla \cdot \textbf{U} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial z} =0 $$

Note that since the curl of any gradient field is $0$, the solution will not be unique, i.e. if $\textbf{V}$ is a solution, then another solution is $\bar{\textbf{V}} = \textbf{V} + \nabla \phi$, where $\phi(x,y,z)$ is some scalar function.

It's enough to find one particular solution, then add on an arbitrary gradient field at the end. A solution can be found by setting one of the components of $\textbf{V}$ to $0$. Let's say $H=0$ so the system is reduced to

\begin{align} 
- \frac{\partial G}{\partial z} &= A \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} &= B \\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= C
\end{align}

Then integrate the first two equations

\begin{align} G &= - \int A\ dz + g(x,y) \\ F &= \int B dz + f(x,y) \end{align}

At this point, the two arbitrary functions leftover from integration should be set so that the third equation is satisfied

$$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = -\int \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} \right)dz + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = C $$

Suppose that

$$ -\int \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} \right) dz = C + h(x,y) $$

where $h(x,y)$ is a known function, then we must have

$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + h = 0 $$

To make it easy again, we can arbitrarily set $g=0$ and $f = \int h\ dy$

Comment: "To find a particular solution, you can set one of the components of $V$ to $0$". How is it reasonable (legitimate)?

Comment: This is correct with a careful choice of integration constants. Note that the integration constant in the two integrations in $z$ direction is still a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You just need to find *one* valid solution, then add on an arbritrary gradient field at the end. Any solution will be fine, so you can make an educated guess that makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: Then you can get in difficulties in the last equation. $$F(x,y,z)=F(x,y,0)+\int_0^zB(x,y,s)ds,\\  G(x,y,z)=G(x,y,0)-\int_0^zA(x,y,s)ds\\G_x(x,y,z)-F_y(x,y,z)=G_x(x,y,0)-F_y(x,y,0)-\int_0^z(A_x(x,y,s)+B_y(x,y,s))ds=G_x(x,y,0)-F_y(x,y,0)+C(x,y,z)-C(x,y,0).$$ You need to chose the integration constants $F(x,y,0)=f(x,y)$ and $G(x,y,0)=g(x,y)$ so that $g_x(x,y)-f_y(x,y)=C(x,y,0)$. And while you are free to set $f=0$, you will need to set $g(x,y)=g(0,y)+\int C(s,y)ds$ where, if I see it right, $g(0,y)=c(y)$ is a free (if sufficiently smooth) function.

Comment: You're right. I guess I should clarify that the integration "constants" should be set so that the third equation is satisfied.

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks for the answer..... After writing the arbitrary integration constants, shouldn't we replace indefinite integration with definite integration ($\int^z_0$)?

Comment: Sure, if you want to. I was trying to be as general as possible. You don't always need to integrate from $0$ either.