# commutativity of differentiation and indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I know the Leibniz rule which states that differentiation  and ***definite*** integration with respect to independent variables are commutative.

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(    \int^b_a f(x,t) \ dt \right)
=\int^b_a \left(  \dfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}     \right) dt$$

Is this commutative property also applicable to ***indefinite integrals*** if we ignore the arbitrary constant? For example, will the functions in $LHS$ and $RHS$ of below equation be equal (*ignoring the arbitrary constant*)?

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(    \int f(x,t) \ dt \right)
=\int \left(  \dfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}    \right) dt$$

> **Edit:** In the answer to [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832251/solving-system-of-three-partial-differential-equations), it is written:
>
> > \begin{align} 
> > - \frac{\partial G}{\partial z} &= A \\
> > \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} &= B \\
> > \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= C
> > \end{align}
> >
> > Then integrate the first two equations
> >
> > \begin{align} G &= - \int A\ dz + g(x,y) \\ F &= \int B dz + f(x,y) \end{align}
> >
> > At this point, the two arbitrary functions leftover from integration should be set so that the third equation is satisfied
> >
> > $$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = -\int \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B}{\partial y} \right)dz + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = C $$
>
> Here we are dealing with indefinite integrals. **So how can we take differentiation with respect to $x$ and $y$ inside antiderivative with respect to $z$?**

Comment: Let $F(x,t)$ be the family of functions that satisfy $\frac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial t}=f(x,t)$.  Assuming that the sufficient conditions are met for equality of mixed partals, then $$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial F(x,t)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$$Can you finish now?

Comment: $$f(x,t)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}  \left[  \int f \ dt  \right]$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \ \partial t}\left[  \int f \ dt  \right]$$
$$\int \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \ dt=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}  \left[  \int f \ dt  \right] + g(x)$$

where $g(x)$ is constant of integration..... Am I right?

Comment: You have it now.  Well done.

Comment: thanks..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every indefinite integral can be written in a form of definite integral 
$$\int f(x,t)dt=\int^t_{c(x)} f(x,u)du$$

Let $c(x)$ be a constant(w.r.t. $u,t$) such that both $f(x,u)$ and $f_x(x,u)$ is continuous for $c(x)\le u\le t$ when $s_0\le x\le s_1$. Also suppose $c(x)$ has continuous derivative when $s_0\le x\le s_1$.

Then, by Leibniz’s integral rule, for $s_0\le x\le s_1$,
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int^t_{c(x)} f(x,u)du=-f(x,c(x))\cdot c’(x)+\int^t_{c(x)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,u)\right)du}$$

Please note that the choice of $c(x)$, apart from the conditions for continuity, is quite arbitrary; this is analogous to the $+C$ in the indefinite integral of single variable functions.

You can infer that the constant of integration for indefinite integral of multivariable functions is not as simple as the one-variable case. And, of course, differentiating the indefinite integral makes things even more complicated.

Comment: Thanks... In one of my questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832251/solving-system-of-three-partial-differential-equations), the answerer (after writing down the constant of integration) uses indefinite integrals with respect to variable $z$ instead of definite integral. Isn't it better to write definite integrals from $c$ (constant) to $z$; after we have written down the constant of integration???

Comment: @Joe You pointed out an important mistake. I will try to correct it.